# Selecting random values in a set in mathematica

Tags: select, random, wolfram-mathematica

I have a set which has {0} and other 8 elements, total 9 elements. I want to choose random 3 value in this set and create a 3x1 column matrix. This will repeat all possible choices in the set. How can I do?

Comment: `RandomChoice` can do what you want.

Comment: Ok Pickett, but one situation that we choose will appear only one time. For example the set is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}. And we choose {1,2,3}. So the situation {1,2,3} used and this situation must not appear two time. Ho can we do this?

Comment: I meant `RandomSample` before. Anyway, what is your goal? If you have enough memory and the lists are not too large you could use a combination of `Permutations` and `RandomSample`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Picket said in comment,

- The way RandomSample works will ensure it will not output the same choice twice in a single call
- If your list is small, you can generate all subsets and sample it.

Example

```
RandomSample[Subsets[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {3}], 7]
```

will generate all (20) subsets with 3 (distinct) elements and then pick 7 different uniformly (there are options to weight each member differently, chose the random generator, etc.).

```
RandomSample[Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {3}], 1], 13]
```

will generate all (120) possible ordered selections of 3 distinct elements among a set of 6 elements and give a sample of 13 distinct elements of this list.

If what you want is a random ordering of all possible subsets of size 3, or of all ordered selections without duplicate of size 3 just ask the same way but with the exact number of such sets.

```
 myset = { foo, foo2, foo3, foo5 };
 RandomSample[Subsets[myset, {3}], Binomial[Length[myset],3 ]]

 RandomSample[Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[myset, {3}], 1], 3!*Binomial[Length[myset],3 ] ]
```

(if you ask more than the exact number of possibilities, RandomSample will complain)

Now if your initial set is large so that the set of subsets is impractical for generation time and memory, take advantage of representing set composition by numbers, even if it is not perfect in term of uniform distribution. Say that your initial set has 20 distinct elements. A three digit number in base 20 can represent any selection of 3. If you account for the need to filter out the few with one digit appearing more than once

```
 20^3/(3!*Binomial[20, 3]) // N

 1.16959
```

You are probably safe by generating 25% more numbers than what you need and filtering the ones with repetition:

```
 Cases[IntegerDigits[RandomSample[0 ;; 20^3-1, Ceiling[31*(1 + 1/4)] ], 20, 3], _?(Length[Union[#]] == 3 &), 1, 31]
```

This generates a random sample of 39 distinct 3-digit numbers in base 20 and select the first 31 with no duplicates in the form of a list of 3-coordinates vectors.